# How to Make FabricJS Canvas Responsive

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to make the canvas responsive while keeping the original image dimensions intact. Currently, when I resize the screen, the canvas size remains constant, resulting in a broken viewport at certain screen sizes. How can I make the canvas responsive while maintaining the image's aspect ratio?

The Live Preview of code could be seen on Codepen here -https://codepen.io/TheShankSharma/pen/YzdXQOr?editors=1001

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
const imageInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');
const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
const addTextButton = document.getElementById('addTextButton');
const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');

let originalImage;

imageInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = event.target.result;

        img.onload = function() {
            originalImage = img;
            canvas.setDimensions({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
            const fabricImg = new fabric.Image(img, {
                selectable: false // Prevent image from being selected/moved
            });
            canvas.clear();
            canvas.add(fabricImg);
        };
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

addTextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (originalImage) {
        const text = new fabric.Textbox(textInput.value, {
            left: 50,
            top: 50,
            fontSize: 20,
            fill: 'black'
        });
        canvas.add(text);
    }
});

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (originalImage) {
        const url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = 'edited_image.png';
        link.click();
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container">
<input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
    <br>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <br>
    <input class="my-3 form-control" type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter text">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addTextButton">Add Text</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="downloadButton">Download Image</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: did you try tranform scale for canvas? I mean when user resize the screen apply scaling to canvas, so that it will fit the user viewport